# Particle incident on a potential barrier

Tags: energy, particle-physics, potential, reflection, probability

> Given a step potential $V_0$ at $x=0$ (potential is zero to the left of the origin and $V_0$ to the right towards infinity) and a particle approaches it from the left with energy $E=2V_0$.

I solved for the probability of reflection in this scenario. I used $R=\frac{|B|^2}{|A|^2}$. The 2nd part of the question now asks to consider the case when the particle comes in from the right instead of the left. I solved for the probability of reflection and found that it is different (higher or lower, I forget which one) then when the particle comes in from the left. But my professor said they should be the same! Why is this?? Why is there an equal probability of reflection when coming in from the left vs. the right?

Answer (score -1):

The boundary that is causing the reflection is not the "wall" you might imagine is created by an increase in the potential difference. Rather it is that there is a change in potential at the position $x=0$. It doesn't matter if the change is up or down, they are still two distinct regions.

Light travelling through a pane of glass is reflected from the front and rear surface of the glass, sometimes in a mirror you can see a double or triple image depending on the glass thickness, due to reflection from inside front plane of the glass and off the back wall again.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question of the OP "Why is there an equal probability of reflection when coming in from the left vs. the right?"